# DataGridViewColumn.Frozen with mono 2.10

Tags: c#, mono

I have a problem with Method `DataGridViewColumn.Frozen` with mono on Linux, and googling this problem doesn't helps me.

I'm need to freeze couple of columns of `DataGridView` within C# mono application, and on Windows it's working as expected, but any time i copying my binary to Linux PC, method `Frozen` doesn't work at all.

I have tried `Columns[index].Frozen` and `Columns[name].Frozen` both before and after filling the `DataGridView`.

Is this a bug of my mono version, or i need some additional code to make this work?
I'm using mono 2.10 (unfortunately, i cannot upgrade it) on SUSE Linux.

### UPD

Made a simple application and tested it on mono 4.6.2: same with 2.10, method `Frozen` doesn't work.

Code of testing app:

```
DataTable _tbl = new DataTable();
_tbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
_tbl.Columns.Add("val1", typeof(String));
_tbl.Columns.Add("val2", typeof(String));

_tbl.Rows.Add("1", "val11", "val22");
_tbl.Rows.Add("2", "val11", "val22");

dgvVars.DataSource = _tbl;
dgvVars.Columns["Name"].Frozen = true;
dgvVars.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms is implemented in Mono on the top of System.Drawing. Thus, it is more or less easy to follow the code since there are not P/Invokes.

At the time of writing (February, 2018), I have not found a mention to the property `Frozen` in the DataGridView.cs file.

Also, I've found [DataGridViewTest.cs in searchcode.com](https://searchcode.com/file/115705511/mcs/class/System.Windows.Forms/Test/System.Windows.Forms/DataGridViewTest.cs). If you do a text search for `Frozen`, you'll find:

```
// /* NIE for the moment... */ Assert.AreEqual (true, cell.Frozen, "#cell.Frozen");
```

I think this means that `Frozen` is not implemented. Since Windows Forms has been abandoned by Xamarin, I would not expect to have that fixed anytime soon.

I'm afraid you will have to implement it yourself.

Hope this (somehow) helps.